# Why keras embeding layer has no keys

Tags: python, keras, embedding

```
self.embed = Sequential([Embedding(9488, output_dim=512,input_length=14),
   Activation('relu'),
  Dropout(0.5)], name='embed.0')

inputs_bedding = Input(shape=(10,)) 
xt = self.embed(inputs_bedding) 

=============================
keras_model.save('temp.h5')
with h5py.File('temp.h5', 'a') as f:
model_weights = f['model_weights']
params = util.dig_to_params(model_weights[layer])

def dig_to_params(keras_h5_layer): 
    while not _contains_weights(keras_h5_layer): 
        keras_h5_layer = keras_h5_layer[list(keras_h5_layer.keys())[0]]

    return keras_h5_layer
```

> Error: `keras_h5_layer = keras_h5_layer[list(keras_h5_layer.keys())[0]]`
>
> AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: honestly, I would not save the architecture and the weights separately. Its easier to just do model.save("abc.h5") then you can just load the model

Comment: as far as I know, layers don't have keys, embedded feature do though. Check this out https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/